# Spring Boot File Upload Bad Request 400

Tags: file-upload, parameters, spring-boot, http-status-code-400, bad-request

Hello im writing an Webapplication using Spring Boot and AngularJs and need an simple file upload which is not working at the moment.

I already read that spring boot should autoconfigure the multipart upload itself when the mvc dependency is present.
From :https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

> As part of auto-configuring Spring MVC, Spring Boot will create a MultipartConfigElement bean and make itself ready for file uploads.

Javascript Function which sends  the Request:

```
var postFormData = function (file, url, successCallback, errorCallback, progressCallback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", file);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                successCallback(xhr.status); //File is Uploaded
            } else {
                errorCallback(xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };

    function progress(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            progressCallback(percentComplete);
        } else {
            progressCallback(evt.loaded);
        }
    }

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);

    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    xhr.addEventListener("progress", progress, false);

    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Multipart configuration Bean in my main app class:

```
 @Bean
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize(MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE);
        factory.setMaxRequestSize(MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE);
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
```

Upload Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FileUploadController {

        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;

        @Autowired
        VolumeMetaRepository volumeMetaRepository;

        /**
         * Handles File upload of volumedata
         *
         * @param file Must not be null
         **/
        @RequestMapping(value = "/volumedata/meta/test", consumes= "multipart/form-data", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public void handleFileUpload(
                @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
               /* try {
                    InputStream fileStream = file.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.getOriginalFilename());
                    IOUtils.copy(fileStream, out);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Error uploading file.", e);
                }*/

/*                String filePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                try {
                    file.transferTo(new File(filePath+ "/"  + file.getOriginalFilename()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/
            }
        }
```

And because there are other Stackoverflow Threads were a new Spring boot Version solved the issue Im using '1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT', my gradle dependencies:

```
version = '1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop', version:version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version:version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.hateoas', name: 'spring-hateoas', version:'0.16.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-webmvc', version:'2.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version:version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version:version
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version:'2.1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version:'2.3.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-integration', version:version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket', version:version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.session', name: 'spring-session', version:'1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-redis', version:'1.4.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version:'2.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-remote-shell', version:version
    compile group:'com.google.guava', name:'guava', version:'18.0'

    compile files ('lib/vendor/niftijio.jar');

    compile("com.h2database:h2")

    testCompile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version:'1.1.6.RELEASE') {
        exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }

    testCompile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version:'0.9.1'
    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.3.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"
}
```

The thrown error is:

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2015-01-19T10:22:53.710Z",
  "status" : 400,
  "error" : "Bad Request",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
  "message" : "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present",
  "path" : "/api/volumedata/meta/test"
}
```

It tells me that the "file" parameter is not present, but my Request payload shows that the parameter is there.

```
Request Payload:
------WebKitFormBoundary40qPAhpvA20pd8V1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

C:\fakepath\test.gz
------WebKitFormBoundary40qPAhpvA20pd8V1--
```

Has somebody an Idea what is missing in my configuration, or what could cause the error ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason for the error. It originated not from my Spring controller, but from my angularJS html code.

This was my Upload Input field:

```
 <div class="form-group"
                 ng-class="{ 'has-error': volume_upload_form.file_field.$invalid && volume_upload_form.file_field.$dirty}">
                <label name=file-field-label>Volume Dataset</label>
                <input value=file
                       name=file
                       ng-model=upload.file
                       required
                       id=file
                       file_ext_validation
                       type="file"
                       extensions="nii,NII,gz,jpeg,JPG"/>

                <div class="error"
                     ng-show="volume_upload_form.volume.$invalid">

                    <small class="error"
                           ng-show="volume_upload_form.volume.$error.fileExtValidation">
                        File must be of type ".nii"
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As you can see is use the default ng-model too communicate with my angular controller("upload" is my Controller alias).

```
ng-model=upload.file
```

But Angular does not support the file input html field by default. So only a string containing the file path was stored in upload.file, NOT an actual File Object. I had to write a custom directive:

```
var fileModel = function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}

module.exports = fileModel;
```

Which returns the actual File object. My new upload html code was as follows:

```
<div class="form-group"
                 ng-class="{ 'has-error': volume_upload_form.file_field.$invalid && volume_upload_form.file_field.$dirty}">
                <label name=file-field-label>Volume Dataset</label>
                <input name=file
                       file-model="upload.fileModel"
                       ng-model="file"
                       required
                       file_ext_validation
                       type="file"
                       extensions="nii,NII,gz,jpeg,JPG"/>

                <div class="error"
                     ng-show="volume_upload_form.volume.$invalid">

                    <small class="error"
                           ng-show="volume_upload_form.volume.$error.fileExtValidation">
                        File must be of type ".nii"
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
```

you can see

```
file-model="upload.fileModel"
```

links the File Object from the file input field to the angular controller.
Here is the correct Request Payload.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryR1AXAwLepSUKJB3i
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.nii.gz"
Content-Type: application/x-gzip


------WebKitFormBoundaryR1AXAwLepSUKJB3i--
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue because I named the var incorrect.

In the controller of receiving the file, the `RequestParam("file")` is expecting a param named like "file".

But I named it as something like "bundle". So it's a **bad request**.